# jQuery How to make a variable that shows just the value of a form array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So right now I have a form that is saved in AJAX when submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dispatchForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr("action") || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#form_output").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I then have it where the result is shown in a variable and put into a textbox on the page when the submit button is clicked, via this code.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dispatchSumbit").on("click", function () {
        var text = $("#textarea");
        var local = $("#dispatchForm").serialize();
        text.val(text.val() + time +" - Dispatched to \n" + local);    
    });
});
```

However it shows the whole array which is like this:

[image: Click here]

I want it to just say "[Time] - Dispatched to Test"

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You want to get the value of the specific input to do that. `serialize()` creates `name=value` format and all you want is `value`

Answer (score 2):

`$("#dispatchForm").serialize()` is for creating a `name=value&name=value&...` string for all the inputs in the form, which can be used as the data in an AJAX request. If you just want a single value, use

```
var local = $("#dispatchForm [name=dispatchLocal]").val();
```